# Overwrite Angular 2/4 Component

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular2-components

I have the following situation: I have an Angular app (more precisely, an Ionic app) and want to selectively overwrite components in this app to create multiple variants of the same app. Think of a standard application with customer specific branches.

In my base application, I declare a component like this:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'trip-details',
  templateUrl: 'tripDetails.html'
})
export class TripDetailsComponent {

  @Input() trip: Trip;

  constructor() {}
}
```

It's included in my app.module.ts of course:

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    TripDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ...,
    TripDetailsComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In my specialization of the same application, I would like to replace the TripsDetailComponent with a variant, say, TripsDetailSpecialComponent. How can I accomplish this using Angular's DI? So far, I tried to create a new module for the specialized app that imports the original app and declares the new component, which is annotated with the same selector.

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TripDetailsSpecialComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    TripDetailsSpecialComponent
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class SpecialAppModule {}
```

Of course, I updated the bootstrapping to use the new module:

```ts
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CustomerModule);
```

However, the special component is not used in any place when using this approach.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see what you're trying to do : what is the end goal of that ? Maybe I can find a solution for you if I see the purpose of it.

Comment: Try changing the behavior, not the component. Check the component pattern.

Comment: @trichetriche The idea is to have use case specific information displayed in different variants of the same app. For example, one might have a CRM tool that is always similar, but depending on the profession of the customer the list of customers should show different information (e.g., a car workshop wants to see car make and model, a doctor wants to see age and illnesses). My idea was to have one component for the list cell and then replace this component, similar to using `{provide: Component, useClass: SpecialComponent}`

Comment: Well it looks a bit complicated, because from what you told me, it's only relative to your model. If you want to create a CRM-like application, just make an "all-purpose" component with generic properties, instead of making dynamic components that would try to cover all use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
{
  path: 'trip',
  component: SOME_CONDITION ? TripDetailsComponent: TripDetailsSpecialComponent
}
```

Or if they have to be dynamic at runtime, you can try this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can probably hand craft something with dynamic component loading. The other solution won't work, unfortunately, since it requires me to know all specializations in the base application.